# TimeMachine inProgress file corrupted cannot remove manually

Tags: backup, time-machine

Running M1 with Ventura

The TimeMachine update refuses to pick up from where it left off - I think the HDD was removed too early - I am trying to manually delete the in progress file so it re-syncs and starts again.

sudo tmutil delete -d /Volumes/Time\ Machine\ Backup/Backups.backupdb/XXX -t 2022-10-27-065231.inProgress/

Error 22 - invalid argument

If I remove the -t and double tab - I can see it listed and in finder

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Don't mess with it. Put the disk to one side and keep it safe (until backups no longer needed). Start with a new disk and new TM.  New TM will be to apfs format which is much more robust than your TM to hfs+ backup.

Comment: Right, so can I move the old backups from my old hdd to the new hdd given the storage format is different?

Comment: No. I suggest keeping the current/old backup disk safely unmodified, and start a new backup to a new disk.

Comment: Understood - when completed how do I move the old backups to the new Time Machine instance?